# Efficient mapping between first element of each tuple in a list and the alphabet characters

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of tuples of strings:

```
lst = [('first', 'one'), ('second', 'two'), ('third', 'three'), ('fourth', 'four')]
```

I want to create a mapping between the first element of each tuple and the English alphabet lowercase characters:

- `'first'` mapped to `'a'`
- `'second'` mapped to `'b'`
- `'third'` mapped to `'c'`
- `'fourth'` mapped to `'d'`

I have tried the dictionary

```
dct = {'first': 'a', 'second': 'b', 'third': 'c', 'fourth': 'd'}
```

but I was wondering if there was a more efficient approach which would create the list containing the first element of the tuples and the alphabet list and then iterate them to create the dictionary.

Also, for the alphabet characters, I have tried using `string.ascii_lowercase` but it gives the string not as a list of each character.

I am new with Python so excuse if the question above is basic. I would appreciate any example code for me to understand and learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#zip) and a dictionary [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries):

```
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase
>>> lst = [('first', 'one'), ('second', 'two'), ('third', 'three'), ('fourth', 'four')]
>>> {x[0]: y for x, y in zip(lst, ascii_lowercase)}
{'first': 'a', 'second': 'b', 'third': 'c', 'fourth': 'd'}
```

or if you want to do it in a more 'functional' way:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> {x: y for x, y in zip(map(itemgetter(0), lst), ascii_lowercase)}
{'first': 'a', 'second': 'b', 'third': 'c', 'fourth': 'd'}
```

Comment: Great answer. Could you please add a small explanation about the difference between the two ways in terms of efficiency and also explain the `map` and `itemgetter` functions?

Comment: I hardly can explain them better than docs for [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#map) and [`itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter). As for efficiency, the first version is going to be more efficient as it involves fewer function calls.

Answer (score 1):

```
import string 
lst = [('first', 'one'), ('second', 'two'), ('third', 'three'), ('fourth', 'four')]
alphabetList = [i for i in string.ascii_lowercase ]
dic = {lst[i] : alphabetList[i] for i in range(len(lst))}
print(dic)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can achieve that using dictionary comprehension and using `string` library:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

{lst[i][0]: c for i, c in enumerate(ascii_lowercase)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may create your desired `dict` using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) as:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
lst = [('first', 'one'), ('second', 'two'), ('third', 'three'), ('fourth', 'four')]

my_dict =  dict(zip(list(zip(*lst))[0], ascii_lowercase)) # in python 3
# In python 2, you may just do:
#     my_dict = dict(zip(zip(*lst)[0], ascii_lowercase))
```

OR, even better to use it with [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) as:

```
my_dict = dict(zip(map(itemgetter(0), lst), ascii_lowercase))
```

Value hold by `my_dict` will be:

```
{'first': 'a', 'second': 'b', 'third': 'c', 'fourth': 'd'}
```

---

**Explanation:**

You were almost there. `string.ascii_lowercase` returns a string but you may iterate the string and access the item based on index *(same as you do with `list`)*. For example:

```
my_alphas = string.ascii_lowercase

# Iterate the string, valid
for alpha in my_alphas:
    print alpha

# access based on index, valid
my_alphas[13]
```

*As an additional piece of information even though you don't need this:* If you want to convert the `string` into `list`, you may type-cast it as:

```
my_alpha_list = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
#  ^  will hold all the alphabets in the form of list
```

Comment: I appreciate the explanation. However, I get a 'zip' object is not subscritable and in the interest of learning Python I would like to know why if you can figure it out. Thanks

Comment: @Karim My bad. I haven't seen the Python 3 tag. In python 3, `zip` returns the object of `zip` type and you have to explicitly type-cast it to list in order to make it work. Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for the update. Could you also care add a small explanation of the `itemgetter` approach; why is it better and how it differs?